# Why am I directed to the same page when using routes in react js

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, react-router, react-router-dom

So in my app.js i created Router-Routes-Route tags to direct me to a blank page after clicking on a button that would take me to the link. but it doesn't seem like its working and instead its taking me to the same exact page with a new link that am directed to. also when I write any text it is written on the top of the page after clicking on the button.

Here is my code

App.js Class:-

````
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Component/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./Component/Navbar";
import HeaderBox from "./Component/HeaderBox";
import AMBox from "./Component/AMBox";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Experience from "./Component/Experience";
import Education from "./Component/Education";
import Projects from "./Component/Projects";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Memory from "./Component/Memory/Memory";
import About from "./About";
// import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/Memory" element={<Memory />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Navbar />
      <AMBox></AMBox>
      <Experience></Experience>
      <Projects></Projects>
      <Education></Education>
    </Router>
  );
};
 




export default App;```

This is the way I linked  the memory to get me the link
 
 <NavLinks to="Memory">
            <svg
              class="myClass1"
              viewBox="45 60 400 320"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
         
              <mask id="knockout-text">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" x="0" y="0" />
                <text x="147" y="227" fill="#000">
                  Memory
                </text>
              </mask>
            </svg>
          </NavLinks>
````

```
export const NavItem = styled.li`
  height: 80px;
`;

export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: Pointer;

  &.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
`;
```

The Memory class

```
import React from "react";

const Memory = () => {
  return <div>Memory Page</div>;
};

export default Memory;
```

Before and after clicking on the memory button
[image: before]
[image: after]

I tried doing this but i got an error saying ''Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component.''

```
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/Memory" element={<Memory />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Navbar />
      <AMBox></AMBox>
      <Experience></Experience>
      <Projects></Projects>
      <Education></Education>
      </>
```

Thank you

Comment: You are rendering the routes above all the content, so that's why it above the content in the UI. Other than this I don't understand your question/issue. You are only render 1 route as far as I can tell, what else are you expecting to link to and render?

Comment: I just edited my question at the end   is that what you mean i need to do ?

Comment: yeah thats true. I just updated the imports as well

Comment: I'am expecting it to take me to another blank page

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by I'm rendering a single route. Isn't that how it works so I would be directed to a blank page where I can write the code of it in the Memory.js?. Im sorry, I'm a beginner with react

Comment: I'm saying that the blank page doesn't exist. In fact I want it

Comment: Yeah that the one Im referring to The Memory page

Comment: So basically I want it to work that way--> When i click on the Memory button (the svg) it would take me to another blank page where I can build that page in the Memory.js class

Comment: That's not whats happening . Instead of getting a blank page (which I want) I'm getting the same hoem page but with the new code that im coding on the top. Its Not Blank

Comment: What is your "home page"? Is it all the other code other than `Navbar` component? Do you want `AMBox`, `Experience`, `Projects`, and `Education` to be rendered on their own route?

Comment: Yeah exactly. So the Memory would have only the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've gathered you want a "home page" to be rendered on it's own route, along with `Memory` on its `"/memory"` route. Move `AMBox`, `Experience`, `Projects`, and `Education` into their own route, and render all the routes ***below*** the `Navbar` so they render below it in the page.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/memory" element={<Memory />} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <>
              <AMBox />
              <Experience />
              <Projects />
              <Education />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/memory" >
          <Mem/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

function Home(){
      return (
      <>
      <Navbar />
      <AMBox></AMBox>
      <Experience></Experience>
      <Projects></Projects>
      <Education></Education>
      </>
   )
}

function Mem(){
      return (<Memory />)
}
```

Do make modifications to fit your case

Comment: I did this and I got is error.    ×
Error: [Home] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Comment: yeah just forgot to add return and a fragment <></> to the created function